# Updating Value on Master Sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am quite new to Excel and trying to make a VLOOKUP. So far, so good. I have 2 sheets, let's call them `Sheet A` and `Sheet B`.

`Sheet A` contains the full list of my user profiles, with a unique ID each. 
`Sheet B` contains only a few partial information about the users from `Sheet A`. I used a VLOOKUP here on the IDs and it works nicely.

`Sheet A` can be described as the master sheet with over 4000 rows of users.
`Sheet B`, which contains only a few values (around 300 rows of users) from `Sheet A` automatically gets updated if I change an information in `Sheet A`.

Now, my issue is as follows:
If I update some data on `Sheet A`, it reflects on `Sheet B`. That's perfect. But how can I modify my sheets, such that, even when I make a change on `Sheet B`, it updates the master sheet, `Sheet A`.

To give you an example:

**Sheet A**

id | title | f_name | l_name

**Sheet B**
id | f_name

With a VLOOKUP on `Sheet B`, `f_name`, I can easily pull the data from `Sheet A`. So when I update the `f_name` on `Sheet A`, the data auto gets updated on `Sheet B`. How can I make it such that even if I decide to modify `f_name` on `Sheet B`, it updates `Sheet A`?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if the `f-name` list on sheet B is generated by vlookup formulas, why would you replace those formulas by a value manually? This seems backwards...

Comment: @Plutian Right. The thing is that I am using only `Sheet B` as my working sheet and I need to update information there, instead of going through `Sheet A` and update there. The reason for that is because someone already updated `Sheet B` manually and it's really difficult to redo that process. Since `Sheet B` is linked to `Sheet A`, I'm just trying to reflect he changes made in `Sheet B` to `Sheet A`

Comment: If sheet B is your working sheet where you change values, wouldn't it be better to place all your vlookup formulas on Sheet A instead? It would be fairly awkward to figure out a formula to check which lines have been updated with formulas and which hold manually updated values. Although I'm sure this is possible with VBA.

Comment: @Plutian Yeah I tried to put it on `Sheet A` but since it's the master sheet with all the information, it returns #N/A for the IDs which are not in B. Which actually makes sense. But you're right, it's an awkward situation and VBA might be the only way. I have no idea how to use it though. Might have to go manual. Will leave this question open in case someone has a solution. Thanks

Comment: Referring to "..someone already updated Sheet B manually" statement.. the edited data is only `f_name` right?